# Spring boot add error message to rest response without throwing exception but keeping typed response

Tags: rest, spring-boot

My REST endpoints return `ResponseEntity<SomeDto>` or only `SomeDto`. Out of this i generating swagger to be consumed by front end. Of course the type information `SomeDto` is crucial.

Within my endpoint methods i am doing some basic checks to prevent exception further down the road (fail as fast as possible).

Returning `ResponseEntity.badRequest().build()` in such cases works fine, but i want to add a error message to the body. But adding a `String` to the body is not possible in regards to `ResponseEntity<SomeDto>`.

**Question**
How i can add a error message while maintaining the signature/ contract without the need of raising an exception (see "Effective Java 3rd edition - "Item 69: Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions")?

one (bad) way i see is to add an error message field to all my dtos (could be specified by an interface).

Comment: I have added answer please take a look!

Comment: Aspect oriented programming maybe? Use reflection to intercept the method call at runtime and alter body? :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add error model to individual object instead extend Response model from Base class which has error definition defined, this is how i would implement it.

```
static abstract class ApiResponse {
        enum Status {
            SUCCESS,
            FAILURE,
        }

        @Getter
        @Setter

        private Status status;
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String errorMessage;

    }

    class NamesDto extends ApiResponse {
        @Setter
        @Getter
        String[] names;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "namesdto")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getNames() {
        final NamesDto namesDto = new NamesDto();
        namesDto.setStatus(ApiResponse.Status.FAILURE);
        namesDto.names = new String[]{"john", "doe"};
        return ResponseEntity.ok(namesDto);
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "errordto")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> erroDto() {
        final NamesDto namesDto = new NamesDto();
        namesDto.setErrorMessage("No names found");
        namesDto.setStatus(ApiResponse.Status.FAILURE);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(namesDto);
    }
```

`@Getter/@Setter` are imports from `import lombok.*` package

Comment: this is similar to the one way i see. the problem with this is, that the consumer must be aware of "apiResponse" to know how to handle error. I want the consumer only need to handle by status code and in case of a error code (!=2xx) it could use the error message.

Comment: It is possible to dump same response in json based on ApiResponseStatus

Answer (score 1):

Either using `ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(xxx).build()` or throwing an exception is fine, as soon as the contract is the same.

You are using a lib to generate a Swagger Doc (such as Springfox) ? Well, it does fine for some situations but it can't perform miracles. The documentation generation should not affect how you write your code. In such a case, `@ApiResponse` is what you need.

Comment: the problem with "ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(xxx).build()" is that "xxx" is not the same type of DTO. it is a string (i want to put an error message)

Comment: You should return `ResponseEntity<?>` in this case.